# Firebase auth on firebase-admin not working (node) - Your client does not have permission to get URL "system.gserviceaccount.com" from this server

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

## Problem

I have been using Firebase auth on my client. I am using `firebase-admin` to verify on the server. It has been working great, but not I am migrating to another server and it just stopped working.

This is the important parts of the error message:

## Error message

```
FirebaseAuthError: Error fetching public keys for Google certs: <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>\n'
```

---

## Code

This occurs on 3 different new servers I have tried. It still works on the old server and when I use it locally.

I am ONLY using Firebase for auth, nothing else. On the server side, I'm using a service account like this:

```
import { raise } from "@banjoanton/utils";
import { cert, initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase-admin/auth";

import "dotenv/config";

const serviceAccount = {
    key: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_KEY ?? raise("FIREBASE_ADMIN_KEY missing"),
};

const firebaseBuffer = Buffer.from(serviceAccount.key, "base64");
const firebaseKey = firebaseBuffer.toString("utf8");


const app = initializeApp({
    credential: cert(JSON.parse(firebaseKey)),
});

export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

---

This is the middleware the breaks:

```
import { isDev } from "@app/utils";
import { raise } from "@banjoanton/utils";
import { DecodedIdToken } from "firebase-admin/auth";
import { auth } from "firebase-server";
import { Context, Next } from "hono";
import { UserRepository } from "server";
import { createLogger } from "utils";

const logger = createLogger("authMiddleware");

const allowedPaths: string[] = [];

export const authMiddleware = async (c: Context, next: Next) => {
    const url = new URL(c.req.url);

    if (allowedPaths.some(path => url.pathname.startsWith(path))) {
        await next();
        return;
    }

    if (isDev()) {
        const uid = process.env.DEVELOPMENT_UID ?? raise("DEVELOPMENT_UID is not set");
        c.set("userId", Number(uid));
        await next();
        return;
    }

    const authHeader = c.req.headers.get("Authorization");

    if (!authHeader) {
        logger.info("No auth header");
        return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    if (!authHeader?.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        logger.info("No bearer token");
        return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    const idToken = authHeader.split("Bearer ")[1];

    if (!idToken) {
        logger.info("No id token");
        return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    let decodedToken: DecodedIdToken;
    try {
        decodedToken = await auth.verifyIdToken(idToken);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    if (!decodedToken) {
        logger.info("No decoded token");
        return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
    }

    const userIdResponse = await UserRepository.getIdByExternalId(decodedToken.uid);

    if (!userIdResponse.success) {
        logger.info("No user id in database, creating user");

        const externalId = decodedToken.uid;
        const email = decodedToken.email;
        const name = decodedToken.name;

        if (!externalId || !email || !name) {
            logger.error("No externalId, email or name in decoded token");
            return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
        }

        const user = await UserRepository.createUser({
            externalId,
            email,
            name,
        });

        if (!user.success) {
            logger.error("Could not create user");
            return new Response("Unauthorized", { status: 401 });
        }

        logger.info("Created user with id: ", user.data.id);

        c.set("userId", user.data.id);

        await next();
        return;
    }

    c.set("userId", userIdResponse.data);

    await next();
};
```

And once again, it works perfectly on the old server and locally, just not on any new server I have tried. This is the culprit:

```
decodedToken = await auth.verifyIdToken(idToken);
```

---

Basically, I'm not sure why it does not work. Do I need to update some setting or something in the Google Service Account?

Some other things:

- Hosted on Hetzner in Germany and Finland
- Using Caprover
- Tried creating a completely new Firebase project but could not make that work either

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Hetzner have some IP addresses that are blocked by Google. I had to try with different IPs until it worked.